# Migration from ASP.NET 3.1 to 5.0 stack trace error

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with React in vscode. My project uses Web API, Postgres, ReactJS. When transitioning from .Net 3.1 to .Net 5.0, I encounter this error in my debug console which I would not when running 3.1. Specifically these errors:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll Exception thrown:
> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.dll 5 Exception thrown:
> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Loaded 'C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. Exception thrown:
> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.dll 3 Exception thrown:
> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll fail:
> Marketplace.Services.QueuedProcessingService[0] Error executing
> request in queued processing service action block.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'ILike' method is not supported
> because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually
> happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to
> server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so
> that method can be translated to server.
>
> Here is the code associated with it:

```
private async Task Add(int statusCode, string url){
    var responseErrorList = await responseErrorRepository.GetResponseErrorsAsync();
    var responseError = responseErrorList.FirstOrDefault(re => EF.Functions.ILike(re.Url, url) && re.statusCode == statusCode);
}

private async Task UpdateError(ResponseError error, string url){
    responseErrorRepository.Update(error);
    var referrer = responseError.Referrers.FirstOrDefault(rer => 
    EF.Functions.ILike(rer.Url, url));
}
```

The backend is ASP.NET Web API with a front end in React. There doesn't seem to be many resources online, how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Please share code where you are facing this issue

Comment: `The 'ILike' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation.  `Please post the `ILike` method.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply! Code has been added! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EF.Functions.Like()**

It shoud be `EF.Functions.Like` not `EF.Functions.ILike`.